# SwiftUI MapKit - Multiple annotations in same map

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I've had a look at similar questions but nothing seems to answer this question exactly.

I have a Map view and I want to add pin overlays, as well as a poly line route overlay on top of it. I am very very new at SwiftUI dev (this is my first app), so some help would be appreciated.

At the moment the map only renders the pins, and not the overlay. I'm assuming they need to be put into the same method but cannot figure out how you can return multiple overlays to the mapView.

Here is the Coordinator code:

```
 
    class Coordinator: NSObject,MKMapViewDelegate{
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

          //draw pins
            
            if annotation.isKind(of: MKUserLocation.self){return nil}
            else{
                let pinAnnotation = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "PIN_VIEW")
                pinAnnotation.tintColor = .red
                pinAnnotation.animatesDrop = true
                pinAnnotation.canShowCallout = true
                
                return pinAnnotation
            }
        }
        
        private func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKPolylineRenderer? {
            
            //draw route
            let render = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            render.strokeColor = .orange
            render.lineWidth = 2
            
            return render;
            
        }
    }
```

Here is the output: (no route is drawn). I tried to put the annotations within the same method but couldn't figure out how to return both at the same time (pins are of type MKAnnotationView and the route is of type MKPolylineRenderer...

[image]

Help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Also, you have also shown half of your code. You got mad the last time I posted the links [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you will get better answers if you follow those guidelines. You haven't shown where you actually gave the map the coordinates for the lines. Without data, the function will never do anything. @Rob is right, you need to return an MKRenderer, but there is more to it, and we can't tell if that is all you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a separate method, but it shouldn’t be `private`. Also, the return type should be `MKOverlayRenderer`.